# Inline-blocks won't align unless both contain text

Tags: html, css

Hi I've got two boxes of the same size, but for some reason they won't stay on the same "line", one box contains an image, another contains text. Replacing the Image with text causes them to be aligned the way I want them to be. However not having any text in the box cause them to be unaligned.

http://jsfiddle.net/U3b8r/1/

```
<div class="boxbox">
  <sam-box class="box clickable no-padding" base="170" width="1" height="1">
    <a href="http://placekitten.com/160/160"><img src="http://placekitten.com/160/160"></a>
  </sam-box>
  <sam-box class="box clickable no-padding" base="170" width="1" height="1">
    This is a box  
  </sam-box>
```

I am using a sam box for custom measurements, I can assure you that the size of both elements is the same(174px to be exact).

Comment: What kind of element is a `sam-box` ?

Comment: better use float:left.

Comment: Sam-box is a custom element which allows custom units of measure. https://github.com/samarthwiz/sam-box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use`vertical-align:top;` on inline-block elements. Oh, and 'custom' elements probably won't validate and you may have some x-browser issues too.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2GTR5/1/)

**CSS**

```
.box {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;

  vertical-align:top;

  font-weight: 400;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: I think they'll work just fine when using a polyfill, BTW tested on Safari, chrome, Firefox.

Comment: What do you mean by "x-browser"

Comment: Cross browser...what might work in Chrome might not in IE. If you're having to use a polyfill because you are using 'custom' elements I think it's more work than is required because there any perfectly elements already in place in the spec.

Answer (score 0):

just add a float:left to your .box class

```
float:left;
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/U3b8r/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You might find that adding `overflow:hidden;` to your `.box` class fixes your problem - http://jsfiddle.net/U3b8r/4/

Answer (score 0):

Add float:left for your boxes

```
.box {
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use float left and set the width and height of the divs. Try like below and modified to your needs.

```
.box {
    width:170px;
    height:170px;
    float:left;     
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
    font-weight: 400;
    border: 2px solid transparent;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

since you already give the Css property   `display: inline-block;` then no need to defined the float: left property.

you only need to add below property in your box class

```
.box {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top; /*only add this will work even if the image size is smaller*/
  font-weight: 400;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}
```